# Actions require unique method/path combination for Swagger

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, swagger, asp.net-core-webapi, swagger-ui

I have 2 `HTTP GET` method in same controller and give me this error

> HTTP method "GET" & path "api/DataStore" overloaded by actions - DPK.HostApi.Controllers.DataStoreController.GetByIdAsync (DPK.HostApi),DPK.HostApi.Controllers.DataStoreController.GetAllAsync (DPK.HostApi). Actions require unique method/path combination for Swagger 2.0.

My Controller :

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class DataStoreController : ApiControllerBase
{
    private readonly IDataStoreService _dataStoreService;

    public DataStoreController(IDataStoreService dataStoreService)
    {
        _dataStoreService = dataStoreService;
    }


    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> PostAsync([FromBody] DataStoreCommand dataStoreCommand)
    {
        try
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                await _dataStoreService.PostAsync(dataStoreCommand);
                return Ok();
            }

            var errorList = ModelState.Values.SelectMany(m => m.Errors).Select(e => e.ErrorMessage).ToList();
            return ValidationProblem();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e);
            throw;
        }
    }


    [HttpPut]
    public async Task<IActionResult> PutAsync([FromBody] DataStoreCommand dataStoreCommand)
    {
        try
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                await _dataStoreService.PutAsync(dataStoreCommand);
                return Ok();
            }

            var errorList = ModelState.Values.SelectMany(m => m.Errors).Select(e => e.ErrorMessage).ToList();
            return ValidationProblem();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e);
            throw;
        }
    }


    [HttpDelete]
    public async Task<IActionResult> DeleteAsync(int id)
    {
        try
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                var item = await _dataStoreService.GetByIdAsync(id);
                await _dataStoreService.DeleteAsync(item);
                return Ok();
            }

            var errorList = ModelState.Values.SelectMany(m => m.Errors).Select(e => e.ErrorMessage).ToList();
            return ValidationProblem();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e);
            throw;
        }
    }


    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<DataStoreQuery> GetByIdAsync(int id)
    {
        try
        {
            return await _dataStoreService.GetByIdAsync(id);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e);
            throw;
        }
    }





    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<IEnumerable<DataStoreQuery>> GetAllAsync(string instanceName, string dbname, string userName, string userPass, bool isActive, DateTime? startCreatedDate, DateTime? endCreatedDate, DateTime? startModifiedDate, DateTime? endModifiedDate)
    {
        object[] parameters = { instanceName, dbname, userName, userPass, isActive, startCreatedDate, endCreatedDate, startModifiedDate,  endModifiedDate};
        var parameterName = "@instanceName , @dbname , @userName , @userPass , @isActive , @startCreatedDate , @endCreatedDate , @startModifiedDate , @endModifiedDate";
        try
        {
            return await _dataStoreService.ExecWithStoreProcedure(parameterName, parameters);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e);
            throw;
        }
    }




}
```

My Startup :

```
public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2);

        services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
        {
            c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new Info
            {
                Version = "v1",
                Title = " ",
                Description = " ",
                TermsOfService = "None",
                Contact = new Contact() { Name = " ", Email = " ", Url = " " }
            });
        });
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }

        app.UseMvc();


        app.UseSwagger();
        app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
        {
            c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "My API V1");
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 76):

I changed the controller route to following:

```
[Route("api/[controller]/[action]")]
```

or you can also define explicit route for action as well:

```
[Route("GetById")]
```

Comment: For some reason I don't get `api/v1/[controller]/myroute` in the docs when I use `[Route]`, I just get `/myroute` whilst all the other HTTP verbs have the full api path.  First solution is reasonable though as it seems to pull in the method names as the end points.

Comment: thnx. saved my life

Comment: Simply using: '[Route("api/[controller]/[action]")]' works perfectly

Answer (score 61):

You can resolve it as follows:

```
services.AddSwaggerGen (c =>
  {
    other configs;
    c.ResolveConflictingActions (apiDescriptions => apiDescriptions.First ());
  });
//in the Startup.cs class in the ConfigureServices method
```

or you can put routes to differentiate your methods, for example:

```
[HttpGet("~/getsomething")]
[HttpGet("~/getothersomething")]
```

Comment: Santos The first solution would mean only the first action gets documented in Swagger. Generally you want to avoid undocumented endpoints...

Answer (score 12):

you need to map `id` into `HttpGet`.

```
[HttpGet("{id}")]
public async Task<DataStoreQuery> GetByIdAsync(int id)
{
    try
    {
        return await _dataStoreService.GetByIdAsync(id);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e);
        throw;
    }
}
```

when you specify HttpGet by not providing template, Swashbuckle tries to use default map for both of them. hence conflict occurs.

Answer (score 9):

If method has "Name" in it, then also it throws this error. To fix it,

Change from

```
[HttpGet(Name = "GetWeatherForecast")]
[HttpGet(Name = "GetWeatherForecastById")]
```

To

```
[HttpGet("GetWeatherForecast")]
[HttpGet("GetWeatherForecastById")]
```

Comment: Be Careful with this solution because you are changing the route by using it from for example "api/Forecast" to  "api/Forecast/GetWeatherForecast" and  "api/Forecast/GetWeatherForecastById" for GET methods

Answer (score 5):

You can also merge methods with same endpoints to one with optional parameters. Example of implementation tested in net core 5 project:

```
services.AddSwaggerGen(c => 
{
    c.ResolveConflictingActions(apiDescriptions =>
    {
        var descriptions = apiDescriptions as ApiDescription[] ?? apiDescriptions.ToArray();
        var first = descriptions.First(); // build relative to the 1st method
        var parameters = descriptions.SelectMany(d => d.ParameterDescriptions).ToList();

        first.ParameterDescriptions.Clear();
        // add parameters and make them optional
        foreach (var parameter in parameters)
            if (first.ParameterDescriptions.All(x => x.Name != parameter.Name))
            {
                first.ParameterDescriptions.Add(new ApiParameterDescription
                {
                    ModelMetadata = parameter.ModelMetadata,
                    Name = parameter.Name,
                    ParameterDescriptor = parameter.ParameterDescriptor,
                    Source = parameter.Source,
                    IsRequired = false,
                    DefaultValue = null
                });
            }
        return first;
    });
});
```

Answer (score 4):

If the method name are same then **change the request method** with parameter.
I changed the request method to following :

```
[HttpGet]
    public string products()
    {
        // add other code
        // ex. (return "products()";)
    }


[HttpGet("{id}")]
    public string products(int id)
    {
        // add other code
        // ex. (return "products(int id)";)
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

This is how I specified the unique routes for method name

```
[HttpGet("~/GetWeatherForecast")]
```

Keeping it above the methods

```
[HttpGet("~/GetWeatherForecast")]
public int Get()
{
   return Random.Next(5)
}

[HttpPost("~/InsertAddition")]
public int InsertAddition(int num1, int num2)
{
  return num1 + num2;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding both Route and HttpGet.

```
    [HttpGet]
    [Route(~/GetByIdAsync/{id})]
    public async Task<DataStoreQuery> GetByIdAsync(int id)

    [HttpGet]
    [Route(~/GetAllAsync)]
    public async Task<IEnumerable<DataStoreQuery>> GetAllAsync(string instanceName, string dbname, string userName, string userPass, bool isActive, DateTime? startCreatedDate, DateTime? endCreatedDate, DateTime? startModifiedDate, DateTime? endModifiedDate)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also ignore obsolete methods

```
 services.AddSwaggerGen(swaggerGenOptions =>
 {
     swaggerGenOptions.ResolveConflictingActions(apiDescriptions => apiDescriptions.First());
     swaggerGenOptions.IgnoreObsoleteActions();
     swaggerGenOptions.IgnoreObsoleteProperties();
     swaggerGenOptions.CustomSchemaIds(type => type.FullName);
 }
```