# .Net Core 3.1 swagger API versioning conflicting namespaces url

Tags: c#, .net-core, swagger, swagger-ui, api-versioning

I'm using swagger to generate my API documentation, and now i needed to version some of my endpoints.

So i configured swagger to identify my versions and map the endpoint correctly. But swagger is lossing its track because i used the same class names on diferent namespaces and i get this error:

```
Conflicting method/path combination "GET api/v1/A" for actions - TesteSwagger.Controllers.B.AController.x (TesteSwagger),TesteSwagger.Controllers.A.AController.x (TesteSwagger). Actions require a unique method/path combination for Swagger/OpenAPI 3.0. Use ConflictingActionsResolver as a workaround
```

Here is the example i made to reproduce it

> All my swagger packages are in version 6.0.2.

> I`m using .Net Core 3.1 WebApi default empty template

**Startup.cs:**

```
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddControllers();

            services.AddApiVersioning(
                options => 
                {
                    options.ReportApiVersions = true;
                    options.DefaultApiVersion = new ApiVersion(1, 0);
                    options.AssumeDefaultVersionWhenUnspecified = true;
                });

            services.AddVersionedApiExplorer(
                options =>
                {
                    options.GroupNameFormat = "'v'VVV";
                    options.SubstituteApiVersionInUrl = true;
                });

            services.AddTransient<IConfigureOptions<SwaggerGenOptions>, ConfigureSwaggerOptions>();

            services.AddSwaggerGen(options =>
            {
                options.CustomSchemaIds(x => x.FullName);
                options.DescribeAllParametersInCamelCase();
                options.OperationFilter<SwaggerDefaultValues>();
                options.ResolveConflictingActions(apiDescriptions => apiDescriptions.First());
            });
        }

        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env, IApiVersionDescriptionProvider provider)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }

            app.UseSwagger()
              .UseSwaggerUI(c =>
              {
                  c.DisplayRequestDuration();
                  foreach (var description in provider.ApiVersionDescriptions)
                  {
                      c.SwaggerEndpoint($"/swagger/{description.GroupName}/swagger.json",
                          description.GroupName.ToUpperInvariant());
                  }
              });

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();

            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllers();
            });
        }
```

**Swagger default configuration classes:**

```
    public class SwaggerDefaultValues : IOperationFilter
    {
        public void Apply(OpenApiOperation operation, OperationFilterContext context)
        {
            
        }
    }

    public class ConfigureSwaggerOptions : IConfigureOptions<SwaggerGenOptions>
    {
        public void Configure(SwaggerGenOptions options)
        {
        }
    }
```

**A Controller (v1):**

```
namespace TesteSwagger.Controllers.A
{
    [ApiController, ApiVersion("1.0")]
    [Route("api/v{version:apiVersion}/[controller]")]
    public class AController : ControllerBase
    {
        [HttpPost]
        [ProducesResponseType(typeof(B), (int)HttpStatusCode.OK)]
        public IActionResult x(A a) => Ok(new B());
    }

    public class A
    {
        public int Foo { get; set; }
    }

    public class B
    {
        public int Bar { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**B Controller (v2):**

```
namespace TesteSwagger.Controllers.B
{
    [ApiController, ApiVersion("2.0")]
    [Route("api/v{version:apiVersion}/[controller]")]
    public class AController : ControllerBase
    {
        [HttpPost]
        [ProducesResponseType(typeof(B), (int)HttpStatusCode.OK)]
        public IActionResult x(A a) => Ok(new B());
    }

    public class A
    {
        public int Foo { get; set; }
    }

    public class B
    {
        public int Bar { get; set; }
    }
}
```

The v1 URL of swagger loads just fine, only when i change it to v2 that this erros shows in the screen:

```
Fetch error
undefined /swagger/v2/swagger.json
```

I used the curl generated on the v1 URL to test and everything works just fine, just swagger dont get it

```
// works great
curl -X POST "https://localhost:44312/api/v1/A" -H  "accept: text/plain" -H  "Content-Type: application/json" -d "{\"foo\":0}"

// works great
curl -X POST "https://localhost:44312/api/v2/A" -H  "accept: text/plain" -H  "Content-Type: application/json" -d "{\"foo\":0}"
```

I really dont know if i doing something wrong or swagger really does not support this tipe of versioning.

Any ideas?

Comment: I think you have a namespace TesteSwagger.Controllers.B  and a Class B which is confusing.  the error messages says instead of using ProducesResponseType(typeof(B)) try ProducesResponseType(typeof(TesteSwagger.Controllers.B.B))

Comment: Not working, i fully qualified both parameters and responses in both controllers and still the same problem

Comment: The error message indicates that you need to use a full name (including namespace).  It is not clear which object(s) need to be changed.  I only guessed the it was the B class.  th3ere may be others like this that also need to be changed.

Comment: There are not other objects, this is a clean project created just for simulate the error, these are the only two objects of my solution and the only controllers

Comment: Did you try full names for " x(A a) => Ok(new B())"?  I do not know how swagger is converting the string names to class types, but it obvious is doesn't like the names space with the period followed by the "B".

Comment: Yes, i fully qualified the names of all entities on both controllers on every place they are used as i said

Comment: See :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54267137/actions-require-unique-method-path-combination-for-swagger

Answer (score 1):

First, the names of types are largely irrelevant. Namespaces are not a concept that can typically be conveyed over HTTP and are highly dependent on the media type. Modern JavaScript does have modules, but it's not quite a namespace. Regardless, a .NET namespace will not be turned into a set of JavaScript modules to be represented in JSON; certainly, not by default.

The systemic issue here seems to be that you've defined a Swashbuckle configuration without any actual configuration. Three things have to line up for all the pieces to come together:

1. **Add the Versioned API Explorer** - provides API versioning extensions that collates into groups a la the `ApiDescription.GroupName` using the formatted API version. The configuration in `AddVersionedApiExplorer` helps align that to the typical Swashbuckle formats and examples when versioning by URL segment.
2. **Add Swagger Endpoints** - via `UseSwaggerUI`. It is expected to be one endpoint per API version. The segment value typically maps to the API version group name (e.g. formatted version)
3. **Add Swagger Documents** - configures Swashbuckle to define an Open API (formerly Swagger) document per API version. The key of the document maps to the `ApiDescription.GroupName` and the segment of the endpoint defined in #2.

You have not provided any implementation or configuration for that in #3. As a result, Swashbuckle assumes there is only a single document. Since you have models with the same name **and** in the same document, you get a document generation error. You cannot have duplicate route paths or model names in the same document. You *can*, however, have duplicate model names across multiple versions when you define a document per API version.

> **Side Note:** It is possible to have duplicate .NET type names within the same API version, but you will have to provide an alias. Namespace is never considered for distinctness. Unless it *really* doesn't make sense, I would recommend you use unique types/classes for model names within each set of versioned APIs.

The **ASP.NET API Versioning** [Swagger Sample](https://github.com/microsoft/aspnet-api-versioning/blob/435a17ec5001690e531a1715bc736233a2a938db/samples/aspnetcore/SwaggerSample/ConfigureSwaggerOptions.cs#L26) demonstrates what the configuration should look like in totality. A typical configuration will look something like:

```cs
public void Configure( SwaggerGenOptions options )
{
    // configure Swashbuckle to define a Swagger document per defined API version
    foreach ( var description in provider.ApiVersionDescriptions )
    {
        options.SwaggerDoc(
            description.GroupName,
            new OpenApiInfo()
            {
                Title = "API " + description.GroupName,
                Version = description.ApiVersion.ToString(),
            } );
    }
}
```