# Receiving Swagger error in .Net Core 8.0 Web Api

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, swagger

I created a .NET Core 8.0 web api
I have added two classes that represent api responses that have an identical inner class.

```
 public class House
 {
     public Dimensions dimensions { get; set; }=new Dimensions();

     public class Dimensions
     {
         public int Height { get; set; }
         public int Width{ get; set; }
     }
 }

 public class Garage
 {
     public Dimensions dimensions { get; set; } = new Dimensions();

     public class Dimensions
     {
         public int Height { get; set; }
         public int Width{ get; set; }
     }
 }
```

I have added to methods to the default WeatherForecast controller, that each return one of these response classes:

```
 [HttpGet(Name = "GetHouse")]
 public House GetHouse()
 {
     return new House();
 }

 [HttpGet(Name = "GetGarage")]
 public Garage GetGarage()
 {
     return new Garage();
 }
```

When I run the application, I am getting the swagger page, and it says

Failed to load API Definition

Fetch error
Internal Server Error http://localhost:2965/swagger/v1/swagger.json

I open http://localhost:2965/swagger/v1/swagger.json and I see the following:

An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
SwaggerGeneratorException: Conflicting method/path combination "GET WeatherForecast" for actions - Net8WebApi.Controllers.WeatherForecastController.Get (Net8WebApi),Net8WebApi.Controllers.WeatherForecastController.GetHouse (Net8WebApi),Net8WebApi.Controllers.WeatherForecastController.GetGarage (Net8WebApi). Actions require a unique method/path combination for Swagger/OpenAPI 3.0. Use ConflictingActionsResolver as a workaround
Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerGen.SwaggerGenerator.GenerateOperations(IEnumerable apiDescriptions, SchemaRepository schemaRepository)

Could the issue be the identical classes?

Is there a way around this? A swagger configuration?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why am I getting a conflicting method/path combination for actions error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75120271/why-am-i-getting-a-conflicting-method-path-combination-for-actions-error)

Comment: You gonna have two issues. First one is with Name, it gets ignored. For example if you use HttpDelete and HttpPost on your controller you gonna get swagger generated but error would be with your inner classes. Your best bet is to user Route attribute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`[HttpGet(Name = "GetGarage")]` -> doesn't mean to set the route to be `Get: /WeatherForecast/GetGarage`, it only means to [give a name for the route](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/routing?view=aspnetcore-8.0#route-name).

> Have no impact on the URL matching behavior of routing. Are only used
> for URL generation.

Therefore, to solve your issue, we can change the attribute to `[HttpGet("GetHouse")]` and `[HttpGet("GetGarage")]`.

But we will face another exception

> Failed to generate schema for type - WebApiNet8.Controllers.Garage.
> See inner exception  ---> System.InvalidOperationException: Can't use
> schemaId "$Dimensions" for type "$WebApiNet8.Controllers.Dimensions".
> The same schemaId is already used for type
> "$WebApiNet8.Controllers.House+Dimensions"

This is due to having the same class `Dimensions` both in `class House` and `class Garage`. I'm not sure why you define the classes like this. If there's no specific reason, we can move the `public class Dimensions` out of the `House` and `Garage` class to solve this exception.

Comment: Moving the class out fixed this issue. Two reasons for the original design - first the output came from a Paste from Json which generates the classes like that, and also, since the api responses were from separate third-party apis which could change, I felt it was better encapsulation

Comment: Then I decided to make the Dimensions class internal again, but to prevent the error I named the internal classes with a suffix (Dimensions_House, Dimensions_Garage) so there there wouldn't be a collision, and it worked. This also has the added benefit where if Dimensions changed (ex. adding a Height property) in House but not in Garage, then the change could be made to Dimensions_House without affecting Dimensions_Garage.